# Low Start Clipping Distance

Tags: 3d-view

I have no idea what to do. How do i fix this eye sore?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer: The Problem was my start clipping distance was at the lowest setting. Increase the setting and everything will be good.

Comment: Your model has overlapping geometry causing what is called Z-Fighting.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86383/jagged-black-edges-artifacts-when-modeling/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53825/how-can-i-prevent-my-text-object-from-flickering/53835#53835

Comment: I have already removed all the doubles so it cant be that. Im using the archipack ad on and this is the first time its done this.

Comment: Check also that the clip distance for the viewport is not set to an extremely large range, creating precision errors.

Comment: Yes thats it the clip start distance was way to low.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have double verts. If not, check if you have a duplicate Object in the same place where the artifacts occur. I can't think of anything else.